# How to change Festival server_port

Tags: festival, text-to-speech

Can anyone tell how to change the `server_port` in `Festival`? I tried changing it using

```
set! server_port 1315
```

but after that the `server_port` still has 1314 the default value. Can anyone try to solve this?

Comment: After putting parentheses I was able to change the port.

(set! server_port 1315)

Answer (score 2):

This is an old one but it might be helpful to someone.

To define the festival server port simply use the following command line expression:

```
festival --server '(set! server_port PORT)'
```

Where PORT is your required port. The next example will start festival server on port **1515**

```
festival --server '(set! server_port 1515)'
```